# Python does not distinguish between some unicode characters when used in variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

#### The problem

I for one delight myself by using Unicode literals in my variable names when writing Python 3 code. Today I had a weird bug, which turns out to be due to Python not distinguishing between the variables `ρ` and `ϱ`, as this short code show:

```
ρ = 'hello'
ϱ = 'goodbye'
print(ρ)  # Prints 'goodbye'
```

Is this a bug or a feature? In case of the latter, how/where can I find the set of all such characters which belong together in this manner?

#### Further exploration

This lack of distinction is not present when `ρ` and `ϱ` are used inside strings:

```
a = 'ρ'
b = 'ϱ'
print(a == b)  # Prints False
```

which makes me confident that this is not some encoding problem with my editor/terminal.

We can also confirm that Python is fully aware of precisely which characters we are dealing with, using the `unicodedata` module:

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.name('ρ'))  # Prints 'GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO'
print(unicodedata.name('ϱ'))  # Prints 'GREEK RHO SYMBOL'
```

I have found the same behavior between the pair `φ` (GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI) and `ϕ` (GREEK PHI SYMBOL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[2.3. Identifiers and keywords ¶](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

> All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', 'ρϱ')
'ρρ'
```